# Enum pattern matching as a parameter to a function call

Tags: swift, enums

I've setup a playground with an example:

```
enum CarType : Equatable {
    case wheeled(wheels: Int)
    case flying

    public static func ==(lhs: CarType, rhs: CarType) -> Bool {
        return lhs.enumName == rhs.enumName
    }

    var enumName: String {
        let stuff = "\(self)".split(separator: "(").first!
        return String(describing: stuff)
    }

}


var typesPresentAtMyParty = [CarType.wheeled(wheels:4), .wheeled(wheels:4), .flying]

let aKnownType = CarType.flying

if case aKnownType = typesPresentAtMyParty[2] {
    print("Was the type")
}

func isPresent(type: CarType, inArray: [CarType]) -> Bool {

    return inArray.filter {
        if case type = $0 {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }.first != nil

}

func isWheeled(inArray: [CarType]) -> Bool {

    return inArray.filter {
        if case .wheeled = $0 {
            return true
        }
        return false
        }.first != nil

}


isPresent(type: .flying, inArray: typesPresentAtMyParty)
isPresent(type: .wheeled, inArray: typesPresentAtMyParty)
```

The last line here does not compile. While i can do `if case .wheeled = $0` ignoring associated type as a check, i cannot find a way of doing the same in a function call `isPresent(type: CarType, inArray: [CarType])`, when sending `isPresent(type: .wheeled, inArray: typesPresentAtMyParty)`

Is there a way of writing a function that takes only the valid pattern matching part of the enum as a parameter?

Comment: You could simply pass zero for the associated value. Or will that interfere with the equality check? If yes, then you might want to consider redesigning that check.

Comment: yes but randomly assigning a value is not what i want, i want to just not define a value in it, like when doing the check `if case .wheeled = $0`

Comment: 0 is not a random value :)

Comment: Enums with associated values are like functions, if they require parameters, you need to specify them.

Comment: Well why don't you need to specify it when doing `if case .wheeled = $0` ?

Comment: That's pattern matching, which allows this, constructing enums is a little bit different.

Comment: is it in any way possible to send that pattern matching into a function, all i want is to generalize the check, i don't need to send the enum type, just something that allows me to do that kind of pattern matching in a function

Comment: I don't think that's possible, if you call the function you need to provide a concrete value of the enum. This is also true for the pattern matching, where you are actually passing a concrete enum value, it's just that the left side of the operator allows you to specify partial details.

Comment: @Cristik, enum cases with associated value are not just like functions, they are functions, like `CarType.wheeled` has type `(Int) -> CarType`. And you can pass `CarType.wheeled` as a closure too.

Comment: @user28434 what type is the pattern matching thing? why can it be represented without concrete value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to pass partially constructed enums to a function. Partially constructed enums are not valid values, and they only work in pattern matching because the compiler has a concrete value to work with - the one from the right side of the pattern.

These being said, you could easily rewrite your functions to better, more swiftier versions.

Firstly, you don't need `isPresent`, you can simply use contains:

```
typesPresentAtMyParty.contains { $0 == .flying }
typesPresentAtMyParty.contains { if case . wheeled = $0 { return true } else { return false } }
```

Similarly, `isWheeled` can be shortened (and renamed, for better semantics):

```
func isWheeled(_ carType: CarType) -> Bool {
    if case . wheeled = carType { return true } else { return false }
}
```

which can pe passed to `contains`:

```
let hasWeeled = typesPresentAtMyParty.contains(where: isWheeled)
```