# Operator or function to simplify enum associated value in Swift

Tags: swift, generics, enums, operators

I cannot figure out if there is a way to convert an enum case into one of it's associated values or returning a nil in any kind of generic way that could be applied to an enum. It seems like it should be possible at least theoretically.

What I want to do..

```
let value: TestClass1? = model .> TestEnum.one
// do something
```

What I am doing now..

```
if case .one(value: let value) = self.model {
    // do something
}

guard case .one(value: let value) = self.model else {
    //handle case where self.model != .one
    return
}
//do something
```

Does not compile:

```
infix operator .>
func .><T,U>( _expression: T, _case: (U) -> T) -> U? {
    guard case _case(let u) = _expression else { return nil }
    return u
}
```

Test case:

```
class TestClass1 {}
class TestClass2 {}

enum TestEnum {
    case one(value: TestClass1)
    case two(value: TestClass2)
}

struct TestStruct {

    let model: TestEnum = .one(value: TestClass1())

    func function() -> TestClass1? {
        // what I want to do
        return model .> TestEnum.one
    }
}
```

If anyone has any ideas on how to make the above operator function work I'd love any suggestions.

Comment: This cannot be achieved in swift. Why? I hope this article will guide you:
[Why swift enums with associated values cannot have a raw value](https://medium.com/@PhiJay/why-swift-enums-with-associated-values-cannot-have-a-raw-value-21e41d5ec11)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enum pattern matching as a parameter to a function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52363800/enum-pattern-matching-as-a-parameter-to-a-function-call)